# Find truncation error expression

Tags: differential-equations

Find the ordinary differential equation of a Buck circuit, use the system's own command DSolve to calculate the analytical solution of the equation, and use my own reverse Euler method to calculate the numerical solution of the equation (the step size is 0.00006). Subtract the solutions obtained from the two methods to get the corresponding truncation error curve. How can I get the analytical expression of this curve?

The following is my code. After execution, you will get the truncation error curve.

```
(*DSolve与BackEuler误差,(1),0.00006*)
tstart = 0;
tend = 0.08;
stepsize = 0.00006;
n = (tend - tstart)/stepsize;
(*DSolve*)
sol1 = DSolve[{l il'[t] == vl[t], c vc'[t] == ic[t], 
    ir[t] == -ic[t] + il[t], vl[t] == 24 - vc[t], vr[t] == vc[t], 
    vr[t] == r ir[t], il[0] == 0, vc[0] == 0}, {ir[t], il[t], ic[t], 
    vr[t], vl[t], vc[t]}, t];
{il[t_], vc[t_]} = {il[t], vc[t]} /. sol1[[1]];
pars1 = {r -> 22, l -> 2 10^-1, c -> 1 10^-4};
a = Evaluate[il[t] /. pars1];
b = Evaluate[vc[t] /. pars1];
Dil = Table[a, {t, 0, tend, stepsize}, 1];
Dvc = Table[b, {t, 0, tend, stepsize}, 1];
(*后向欧拉*)
{r = 22, l = 2 10^-1, c = 1 10^-4, vi = 24, initvalueil = 0, 
  initvaluevc = 0};
(*矩阵构造*)
{h = {il, vc}, 
  f = {{1, stepsize/l}, {-stepsize/c, 1 + stepsize/(r c)}}, 
  s = {1/l, 0}};
m = Transpose[{h}];
g = Inverse[f];
m = Table[{initvalueil, initvaluevc}, {i, 0, n}];
il = Table[initvalueil, {i, 0, n}];
vc = Table[initvaluevc, {i, 0, n}];
For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
  m[[i + 1]] = g . (m[[i]] + stepsize*s*vi);
  il[[i + 1]] = m[[i + 1, 1]];
  vc[[i + 1]] = m[[i + 1, 2]];
  ];
(*求误差*)
errort = Table[tstart + stepsize*i, {i, 0, n}];
ilerror = Table[0, {i, 0, n}];
vcerror = Table[0, {i, 0, n}];
For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
  ilerror[[i]] = Dil[[i, 1]] - il[[i]];
  vcerror[[i]] = Dvc[[i, 1]] - vc[[i]];
  ];
ilpeak = FindPeaks[Abs[ilerror]]
vcpeak = FindPeaks[Abs[vcerror]]
p1 = Table[Transpose[{errort, ilerror}], 1];
p2 = Table[Transpose[{errort, vcerror}], 1];
ListLinePlot[p1, AxesLabel -> {"s", "il[t]/A"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"BackEuler"}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[p2, AxesLabel -> {"s", "vc[t]/V"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"BackEuler"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: You might rewrite the numerical approximation as a piecewise-polynomial (perhaps even linear) function. Then just subtract from the analytic solution to get the truncation error expression.